# Why does Phonegap replace my icon?

Tags: android, cordova, android-icons

I've followed tutorials and solutions to Phonegap icon issues here on SO.  From what I'm reading it looks like, if I'm building locally, I need to replace the PG icons in platforms/android/res/drawable (there are 3 diff folders in drawable that contain the icon) with my own.  That is what I am doing.  Here's where it gets weird.  I replace these icons with my own (different icon, same name), then go to Terminal and do `phonegap build android`, and then if I navigate back to the drawables folders I see that my new icons have been replaced yet again with the default Phonegap robot icons.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in fact to use this code block in `config.xml` at the root level (same level as www directory):

```
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/ldpi.png" platform="android" density="ldpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/mdpi.png" platform="android" density="mdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/hdpi.png" platform="android" density="hdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" platform="android" density="xhdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" platform="android" density="xxhdpi" />
<icon src="www/res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" platform="android" density="xxxhdpi"/>
```

Making sure, obviously, that those paths lead to your icons.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that the `platform` folders are rebuilt every time you do a `build` or `run` from the PhoneGap CLI so you don't want to replace them in there manually. Instead you should keep them in a folder somewhere in the root of your project (named whatever you'd like), then refer to their paths in the `config.xml` file for the given platform. The PhoneGap CLI will will copy them down to the platform level for you automatically when you do a `build`, `run` etc. For Android it will copy them down to the `platforms/android/res/drawable*` folders specifically based on their density (`ldpi` etc). You just need to make sure you specify the right `density` attributes in the config.xml (or width/height for iOS) to match the correct paths in your root project where those can be found.

For instance, in the config.xml you may have the following for Android icons:

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
</platform>
```

Where `resources` is located in the root of your project at the same level as the `www` folder (ie: `myProj/resources`).

You can find more details about this [in the Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/images.html) for more details on configuring your icons.

If for some reason it doesn't work, check to make sure you have a recent version of the [PhoneGap CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap) or update to the latest.

~Holly

Comment: And the config.xml file should be located inside `www` or at root level?

Comment: Copying your code and following your answer to the letter did not work.

Comment: @lola_the_coding_girl Can you please provide more details on what the result was or specific error messages?

Comment: @devgirl - There was no error just the icon remains the Phonegap robot.

Comment: If you look in your drawable folders do you see an icon.png file at all? For instance at path `~/myProj/platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/`? Also, please verify that the `resources` folder is in the root of your project (not in the `www` folder) and double-check that your paths and file names are correct. Then run your commands with the `-d` option to enable verbose mode so debugging info will display to get a better idea of what is going on. For instance `$ phonegap build -d`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the icon configuration in you `config.xml` file inside your `www` root folder. Try adding something like this:

```
<platform name="android">
       <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
       <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
       <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
       <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
 </platform>
```

The create these folders containing your icons and execute `phonegap build android`.